# ¿Por que Left Join usando LINQ C# y fechas como campo de unión da como resultado NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Lo que pretendo hacer es tener una lista con un rango de fechas a la que le quiero hacer un left join con otra tabla en la que hay fechas que coinciden. 
En el código de ejemplo solo existen los días pares y los impares los establezco a null a modo de prueba.
En el código de producción las jornadas vienen de una tabla en la que puede haber varios registros de horario en una misma fecha.

El resultado que busco es el siguiente:

```
Fecha       Entrada     Salida   Descripción
-----       --------    ------   -------------
01/05/2019  -           -        -
02/05/2019  -           -        -
03/05/2019  -           -        -
04/05/2019  -           -        -
05/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
06/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
07/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
08/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
09/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
...
20/05/2019  09:00       14:00    Turno mañana
...
```

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente, pero da como resultado NullRefernceException:

```
var fechas = Enumerable.Range(1,31).Select(c=> new DateTime(2019,05,c)).ToList();
var jornadas = Enumerable.Range(5, 20).Select(c => new {StartTime= new DateTime(2019, 05, c, 09,00,00),
                                                            EndTime =  new DateTime(2019, 05, c, 14,00,00),
                                                            Subject = "Turno mañana"
                                                        }).ToList();

var resumenJornadasMes = from f in fechas
                      join j in jornadas on f.ToShortDateString() equals j.StartTime.ToShortDateString() into fechasJornadas
                      from fj in fechasJornadas.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new 
                      {
                          Fecha = f.ToShortDateString(),
                          Entrada = fj.StartTime == null ? "-" : fj.StartTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                          Salida = fj.EndTime == null ? "-" : fj.EndTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                          Descripcion = fj.Subject == null ? "-" : fj.Subject,
                          //Horas = j.Horas == 0 ? 0 : j.Horas,
                        };
resumenJornadasMes.Dump();
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas el `DefaultIfEmpty()` lo que debes evaluar si tiene un valor o no es el `fj`, ese error se genera porque quieres acceder a `StartTime` cuando fj es null

Entonces quedaria algo como ser

```
var resumenJornadasMes = from f in fechas
                      join j in jornadas on f.ToShortDateString() equals j.StartTime.ToShortDateString() into fechasJornadas
                      from fj in fechasJornadas.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new 
                        {
                            Fecha = f.ToShortDateString(),
                            Entrada = fj == null ? "-" : fj.StartTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                            Salida = fj == null ? "-" : fj.EndTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                            Descripcion = fj == null ? "-" : fj.Subject,
                        };
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro!!. Es obvio. No se como no lo he visto.